# PHP Array delete an entire array by one element value

Tags: php, arrays

So this is how my Array ($dataArray) looks oks like:

```
Array 
( 
 [0] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => Date 
   [1] => Time 
   [2] => Duration 
   [3] => Info 
   [4] => Client
   )
 [1] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => 2021-12-01 
   [1] => 10:45:43 
   [2] => 237 
   [3] => Some text from  
   [4] => Client 1 
   ) 
 [2] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => 2021-12-01 
   [1] => 11:29:13 
   [2] => 77 
   [3] => Nothing important 
   [4] => Client 2 
   ) 
 [3] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => 2021-12-01 
   [1] => 11:53:03 
   [2] => 44 
   [3] => anonymous 
   [4] => Client 1 
   )
```

I need to Loop trough it to search the Client Names, and if i find the matching name in the Element 4 then delete the entire Array.

```
$ExportKDname = "Client 1"
foreach($dataArray as $key => $sub_array) {
    if($sub_array[4] == $ExportKDname) {
        unset($dataArray[$key]);
        break; 
    }
}
  
  print_r($dataArray);
```

But with this code none of the arrays will be deleted. And I just can not find the right way to do it.

The Final array what I need to look like if we find the "Client 1" in the array would be like this:

```
Array 
( 
 [0] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => Date 
   [1] => Time 
   [2] => Duration 
   [3] => Info 
   [4] => Client
   )
 [1] => Array 
   ( 
   [0] => 2021-12-01 
   [1] => 11:29:13 
   [2] => 77 
   [3] => Nothing important 
   [4] => Client 2 
   )
```

Comment: That code should work just fine, in fact it does. It will only delete the first occurance it finds of course

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on your exportKDname variable. However my guess is that you have whitespace somewhere in your names as Riggs is correct that the code would generally work fine. Trim both your subfield and your exportDKname variable.

Comment: First of all, why you put break If you need to remove 2 elements?

Comment: Remove break, also be sure that $sub_array[4] is not containing any extra spaces, for that you can do `if (trim($sub_array[4]) == $ExportKdName)`

Comment: [Demo of code working, your code](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xq8xvd8n) or comment the `break;` to remove all occurances of `Client 1`

Comment: well that’s it @RiggsFolly. The break; was the problem. And because I need the first row i did this too: `foreach ($dataArray as $key => $sub_array) {
    if ($sub_array[4] !== $ExportKDname && $sub_array[4] !== "Client") {
      unset($dataArray[$key])
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if condition you are saying "if u match with `$sub_arr[4] == $ExportKDname` unset it and stop the loop". the machine doing that. when it matched first time it removes and stoping. If u wanna delete all match do not write `break;` let it continue. So delete or make it comment `break;` line.

Answer (score 1):

You can `array_filter` your variable and check if value is `in_array`.

With PHP 7.4+ syntax it should look like this:

```php
$result = array_filter($dataArray, fn ($innerArray) => !in_array('Client 1', $innerArray));
```

Comment: Arrow functions were introduced in PHP 7.4